# Redefinition of virtual method outside of class declaration C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I am trying to use a public C++ library and extend it for my purposes. To extend it, I need to change a single virtual method within a single class. The method I am trying to override is part of an inherited class. I posted essentially what I need to do in the code below. I don't really want to rename the function because it is used in a multitude of other places and I don't want to change the source code of the library because it works for some cases, but not mine specifically.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void getName() = 0;
};

class Dynamic : public Base {
public:
    virtual void getName() {
        std::cout << "Wrong answer\n";
    }
};

//Error in redefinition of class method
void Dynamic::getName() {
    std::cout << "Right answer\n";
}

int main()
{
    Dynamic mydynam;
    mydynam.getName();
}
```

Comment: You can only have one implementation/definition of `Dynamic::getName()`.

Comment: You can't redefine a method. What's stopping you from changing the definition in `Dynamic`?

Comment: You can derive from `Dynamic` and override the method in the derived class.

Comment: If you want to extend it, the function is already virtual, which explicitly allows you to derive a class from `Dynamic` (or from `Base` depending on need) and use that instead.   All you need to do is ensure that uses of that class are via a pointer or reference (`Base *`, `Base &`, `Dynamic *`, `Dynamic &` , etc) and your code will work as intended.   In any event, you can't simply redefine `Dynamic::getName()` like that - only one definition of the function is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example based on the comments above.
The MyDynamic class is derived from the Dynamic class with the function re-implementation.
It will give you the right answer.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void getName() = 0;
};

class Dynamic : public Base {
public:
    virtual void getName() {
        std::cout << "Wrong answer\n";
    }
};

////////////////////////
class MyDynamic : public Dynamic {
public:
    void getName() {
        std::cout << "Right answer\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyDynamic mydynam;
    mydynam.getName();
}
```